# How can i configure L3 switch and DHCP server?

Tags: cisco, switch, packet-tracer

I'm stuck with configuring L3 sw + L2 sw + dhcp server. My scheme is:
[image]

I can't take ip addresses to computers in different VLAN's.
I have two dhcp pools:
[image: enter image description dwhere]

Configuration on L3 switch:

```
ip routing
spanning-tree mode pvst
interface FastEthernet0/1
switchport trunk allowed vlan 10
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk

interface FastEthernet0/2
switchport trunk allowed vlan 20
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport mode trunk

interface FastEthernet0/3
switchport access vlan 30
switchport mode access

interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown

interface Vlan10
mac-address 00d0.ba4b.a601
ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address 192.168.1.1

interface Vlan20
mac-address 00d0.ba4b.a602
ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address 192.168.1.1

interface Vlan30
mac-address 00d0.ba4b.a603
ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
```

L2 switches with almost similar conf, just different vlan's:

```
spanning-tree mode pvst

interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access

interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
```

DHCP server:

```
static ip: 192.168.1.1
gateway: 192.168.30.1
```

So, what i did wrong? What should i do for properly work ?

2:07:
I've changed VLAN1 and up this interface, plus set another dhcp ip,so now on my L3:

```
interface Vlan1
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 1.1.1.5
!
interface Vlan10
 mac-address 00d0.ba4b.a601
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 1.1.1.5
!
interface Vlan20
 mac-address 00d0.ba4b.a602
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 1.1.1.5
!
interface Vlan30
 mac-address 00d0.ba4b.a603
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 1.1.1.5
!
```

DHCP server:

```
IP: 1.1.1.5
Gateway: 1.1.1.1
```

But it still doesn't work. And i don;t know how to don't set mac-address,i think it was by packet tracker automatically.
Should i up VLAN1's svi on L2 switches?

Comment: Where is the SVI for VLAN 30?

Comment: @RonMaupin I've just added `interface Vlan30
 mac-address 00d0.ba4b.a603
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0` and set this ip to gateway on DHCP server, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Start with static network configuration and make sure you can ping each host and dhcp server back and forth. Once it works then you can implement your dhcp. Your problems are basic configuration issues like default gateways etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DHCP server address is not in the network where it is connected. It will never use an address in a different network for its gateway. The gateway is, by definition, in the same network as the host, and it is used by the host to get to addresses not in its network.

You either need to change the DHCP server's address, or you need to change the network to match the DHCP server's network.

Also, there is no reason to specifically set the MAC address on any VLAN.

Since you have the DHCP server connected to VLAN 30 on `F0/3`, you can change the DHCP servers address to `192.168.30.2` with a gateway of `192.168.30.1`. Then just change the helper addresses to `192.168.30.2`.

Comment: Edit your question with the configuration. It is impossible to read in a comment.

Comment: i've just added

Comment: You still have the DHCP server connected to VLAN 30. The DHCP server needs an address in VLAN 30, and VLAN 30 doesn't need a helper address since the DHCP server is on that VLAN.